# Choose a class for my table after button click? (HTML table)

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

I have 2 classes declared in a css file (StyleSheet1.css), .Class1 and .Class2. How do I choose between those two classes after CLICKING A BUTTON for my table tag?

```
<link href="Styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<table class="Class1">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello World!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS File:

```
.Class1
{   
    background-color: Blue;
}
.Class2
{
    background-color: Red;
}
```

As much as possible I want to change classes using C# if possible, but if not, javascript maybe?

I'm very new to ASP and C#, with a little experience in HTML.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Javascript and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Please find the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn1').click(function () {
                $('#tbl1').toggleClass('Class2');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .Class1
        {
            background-color: Blue;
        }

        .Class2
        {
            background-color: Red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="Class1" id="tbl1">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello World!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <button id="btn1">change</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry it says "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined." I must be missing something.

Comment: This requires the use of the jQuery library

Comment: I see. How do I refer to that?

Comment: That means you haven't imported the JQuery library. In my code it's imported from the google CDN. Which is done in line <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I see. Thank you. It works now. If you don't mind me asking, is this the simplest way? To use jQuery for changing classes?

Comment: It depends on your requirements, jQuery is great, but don't use it as a substitute for learning the basics of javascript. If you are wanting to change the class based on some server side behavior see my answer. Also this answer wont work if your button causes a post back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using asp.net webforms (not MVC), and want to do this serverside,  make the table a control by adding `runat="server"` and giving it an ID

```
<table class="Class1" id="myTable" runat="sever">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello World!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now you we be able to work with the table server side in the button click event (or at just about any stage of the page life cycle. You would use something like the following:

```
string cssClass = string.Empty;

if(/*What ever to determine to use class 1*/)
{
     cssClass = "Class1";
}
else
{
     cssClass = "Class2";
}

myTable.Attributes["class"] = cssClass;
```

You could do this in one line with:

```
myTable.Attributes["class"] = /*Condition to determin class 1*/ ? "Class1" : "Class2";
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me this concept. It also works and gave me another useful option and insight.